# How can I save correctly in an object after use the "each" function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, each

I have this function:

```
changeTarea: function(){

var self = this;
$("#select_tarea_id").change(function() {
    var id_tarea = $("#select_tarea_id").val();

$.each(self.objTareasFlot, function(index,value) {

    for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++){

        if(value[i].Id == id_tarea){ 
        self.objTareasFlotFinal.Id=value[i].Id;
        self.objTareasFlotFinal.Id_proyecto=value[i].Id_proyecto;
        self.objTareasFlotFinal.nombre_tarea=value[i].nombre_tarea;
        self.objTareasFlotFinal.porcentaje=value[i].porcentaje;   
        }  
    }
  console.info(self.objTareasFlotFinal);
 });
});
},
```

With `$("#select_tarea_id").change(function() {` I get the Id of the option from a dropdown.

In `self.objTareasFlot` I have this (I show 3 examples):

[image]

For example if I select an option in the dropdown with the Id = 221, and with `if(value[i].Id == id_tarea){` I check if the Id from the dropdown is the same from `value[i].Id`.

Example with `console.info(value[i].Id,"=",id_tarea);` show this:

[image]

So I need this:

If the Id from the dropdown is 221 and I check with `if(value[i].Id == id_tarea){` I need save in a object only the information with the id 221.

And with `console.info(self.objTareasFlotFinal);` I print:

> Object {Id: "221", Id_proyecto: "15", nombre_tarea: "Corregir base de datos", porcentaje: "85"}

But exist 2 Id with 221 so i need save and print :

[image]

How can I do this?
Sorry for my english I did try to explain of the better way

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly, then use this:

```
changeTarea: function(){

var self = this;
$("#select_tarea_id").change(function() {
    var id_tarea = $("#select_tarea_id").val();

$.each(self.objTareasFlot, function(index,value) {

        if(value.Id === id_tarea){ 
        self.objTareasFlotFinal.Id=value.Id;
        self.objTareasFlotFinal.Id_proyecto=value.Id_proyecto;
        self.objTareasFlotFinal.nombre_tarea=value.nombre_tarea;
        self.objTareasFlotFinal.porcentaje=value.porcentaje;   
        }  
 });
 // note that console, will log the object reference asynchronously
 // this means when browser js thread is finished
 console.info(self.objTareasFlotFinal);
});
},
```

Comment: Hi, but doesn't exist self.objTareasFlot.tareas , self.objTareasFlot have all the array with the information

Comment: but if i said In self.objTareasFlot I have this (I show 3 examples) , and I show a pic , why is not clear?

Comment: in the console image it says `object tareas` and inside this the array, this was not clear, actually more are not clear in your question since the names in source code are different and in console output are different, but anyway

Comment: wow.. yes!  sorry , the pic is bad for the name but the results are the same, I edit now.

Comment: your new answer print : object {}

Comment: is `self.objTareasFlotFinal` an array or object?

Comment: i dont understand what `self.objTareasFlot` and `self.objTareasFlotFinal` are (arrays or objects) and what they contain. if you can clarify that, i can update the answer

Comment: self.objTareasFlotFinal is a object

Comment: all are object , self.objTareasFlot have the information of the pic , and self.objTareasFlotFinal is a new object where i want save the information of the function , but all is a object

Comment: and where are the arrays then? i still dont understand, please take console.log output and update your question (not image, actual text output)

Comment: But why you are looking for an array?

Comment: `console.log(self.objTareasFlot);` exactly the structure of this object, and `console.log(self.objTareasFlotFinal);`

Comment: your question mentions arrays inside "*In self.objTareasFlot I have this (I show 3 examples):*", please clarify, this is a waste of time

Comment: if it is an object wher are the keys? again `console.log(self.objTareasFlot);` and `console.log(self.objTareasFlotFinal);` exactly the structure of these variables